# Crossing English channel in a boat

Tags: python, grib

[image]

GRIB file = (U-V) component. from
[enter link description here](https://marine.meteoconsult.co.uk/marine-services/grib-files)

GRIB represents currents. Vectors(U-V) blue arrows and a color scale --> Magnitude and direction. Blue'ish to the left. Yellowish to the right.

I am moving with my boat in steps of 1 hour, see attached animated gif. I takes about 12 hours to cross the English channel.

If there were no currents I would go in a straight line. However there are time dependent currents which moves the boat to left and later on to the right. How to calculate sinusoidal  yellow path in python instead of me manually calculating it?. So for each time dependent position I need corresponding U-V component for that particular time interval. So 11 U-V components.

Comment: You would need to start at either Fishbourne or East Cowes from the north side Isle of Wight?

Comment: Oh this this was just an example. I am going from island of Alderney to a point just south of the isle of Wight. I just want to use some code for a fairly simple calculation. Just need U-V component for each hourly timestep. Easier said the done. I tried some things but all a dead end. I would have thought I simple thing like this is easy to write in code or somebody else must have written in code.

Comment: There are 2 major shipping lanes in the English Channel your example is crossing both - look at https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/home/centerx:-0.2/centery:50.1/zoom:8

Comment: Also the tides and currents around the Isle of Wight are ferocious and I suspect the same is true around the Chanel Islands (though I've never sailed there).

Comment: Indeed but was looking for calculation in python.

Answer (score 0):

Solved use SAMPLE in ArcGIS Pro. It will then take the raster value for each timeframe as the boat is progressing, in this case 1 hour.
The 'time dependent' points will be matched by time of the underlying velocity raster. Some simple arithmetic u & v does the rest. You can even change the boat speed easily.